# Multiple bots handling with a botframework project

Tags: botframework

I started working with bot framework. My idea is to work with multiple bots within the same project through the controller replacing MessagesController with multiple controllers. 
But bot framework registration gives unique MicrosoftAppId and MicrosoftAppPassword, while Web.config in template of BotApplication seems to have support for a single bot in a project. 
How can I configure the project so that, a single project can handle multiple bots supporting Skype/FB/... ?

Comment: Will the bots be providing the same functionality and the only thing that will change is the channel from where the users should be able to use it?

Comment: The bot could have different functionality, one might be Weather bot (Weather forcast for the place) and another Time Bot ( current time in the place).

Answer (score 0):

To have different bots in multiple controllers within the same project you should use the [BotAuthentication](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Connector/BotAuthentication.cs#L15) attribute on each of them and pass the different MicrosoftAppId and MicrosoftAppPassword (see [this](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/connectormisc.html#securing)).

You will still need to register all the different bots to get the MicrosoftAppId and MicrosoftAppPassword for each of them.

Here are some related resources from the BotBuilder's GitHub:

- [BotAuthentication problem](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/867)
- [Support multiple AppSecret and AppId](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/205)
- [How to pass MicrosoftAppPassword to BotAuthentication attribute](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/989)

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

I am here with the same problem and also haven't found answer, but I suppose that multiple bot handling possible using **Microsoft.Bot.Connector.MicrosoftAppCredentials** class.

Maybe this code helps

```
MicrosoftAppCredentials credentials = new MicrosoftAppCredentials(
                    appId: yourAppId, 
                    password: yourAppPassword
                );
ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl), credentials);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample showing how you can configure the Conversation.Container with the right MicrosoftAppCredentials and use a simple MultiCredentialProvider to authenticated multiple MicrosoftAppId and MicrosoftAppPassword.
[Conversation.SendAsync Authentication using custom multi-tenant authentication (Bot Builder 3.5.2)](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/2258#issuecomment-280506334)